# Find all IDs starting with a certain word with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to find all  tags with IDs starting with **"pub"**, like: `<*div id="pub-1">` and `<*div id="pub-foo">` at same time to store those ID results and insert them in a array. I have the following code:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var fs = require('fs');



var data = fs.readFileSync('sites.csv')
    .toString() 
    .split('\n') 
    .map(e => e.trim()) 
    .map(e => e.split(',').map(e => e.trim())); 
(async () => {
  
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        try{
        const url = data[i];
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            args: ['--window-size=1920,1080'],
            defaultViewport: null
            });
        const page = await browser.newPage(); 
        await page.goto(`${url}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
        console.log('Loading page: '+ data[i]);
        const spanVal =  await page.$eval('#pub-1', el => el.innerHTML); // my problems lies here
        
        
        
        console.log('\n \n \n Log: '+ spanVal)

       
        await browser.close();
    } catch(err){
        console.log('Error ' + err)
    }

    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Any suggestion about code quality is also welcome. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the selector `[id^="pub"]` to get IDs that start with `pub`. Iterate over matches with `$$eval` instead of `$eval`, and map to each one's innerHTML.

```
const spanVals = await page.$$eval('[id^="pub"]', elms => elms.map(elm => elm.innerHTML));
```